# Insert array into redis from NodeJS

Tags: node.js, redis, node-redis

I have an array which I fill up in a for like this:

```
var obj = [];
for(i = 0; i < data.bids.length; i += 1) {
    obj.push(JSON.parse(data.bids[i][0]));
}
```

After that I verify if the array contains the desired values (it contains):

```
console.log("Array after the for: \n");
console.log(obj);
```

I try to save this under a redis key, but the `reply` is `undefined`

```
client.set('order-book:buy:bitstamp', obj, function(err, reply) {
    console.log(reply);
});
```

I've also tried with `rpush`, but no luck.
What could be the problem?

Comment: Did you check `err`?  .set expects a string, it looks like you want `client.set(key, JSON.stringify(obj), function (err, reply) { if (err) { console.error(err); } console.log(reply); });`

Comment: `client.rpush(key, array, callback)` is likely what you'll end up with since list is the more natural data type for your data, it'll fail if the key is already set to some other data type (string if you used a set)

Comment: It worked with `JSON.stringify`, if I use `rpush` I get `undefined`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can check here which types are compatible as redis values
[data-types-intro](https://redis.io/topics/data-types-intro).

If you need to save array of objects in redis, the only way to do this is by using `JSON.stringify(obj)`.
So in your example it would look something like:

```
const redisValue = JSON.stringify(obj);
client.set('order-book:buy:bitstamp', redisValue, function(err, reply) {
    console.log(reply);
});
```

When reading data from redis you can easily use `JSON.parse(redisResponse)`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution that I am using  to add array into redis.
But one problem is that we have to handle duplication of data while inserting.Currently redis is inserting duplicate data into array if data already exists into array. So right now I don't have any idea how to handle like we can handle it by javascript or by redis.

[It is link for redis command for list that we can use](https://redis.io/commands/?group=list)